# App store provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone

I created one distribution profile for app store submission. Can i test my application in device with the same profile.

Or otherwise i need to create some other profile with ad hoc distribution?

Comment: It is listed in code sign block. I selected that and run the application in device. Xcode throw alert that "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

Comment: @XCodeMonkey i think ad hoc distribution is different from the app store submission one.

Comment: What my question is can i test the application with app store distribution profile? If no then what profile i should use to test the application? is it ad hoc?

Comment: NO, you need ad hoc distribution for test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have need to create `ad hoc` distribution profile for test. You cann't test with distribution profile`(app store submission)`. read this About [Store Provisioning Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html) and Creating Store Provisioning Profiles

Comment: Right. As of today (iOS 8.3) I can confirm that while an `ad hoc` distribution profile will work for deploying the app to a device, using an `AppStore` distribution profile will throw up an Entitlement error (even when your entitlements are all fine and working with the `ad hoc` profile!)

Answer (score 3):

You can not use an app store provisioning profile to test on a device. You can use an ad hoc profile, or a development profile.

Both ad hoc and development profiles require you to specify your device id.

The difference between an ad hoc and a development profile, is that a development profile can be used to debug. That is, you can use Xcode to build and install the app right on your device, and then step through code as the app is running to see values variables hold etc.

An ad hoc profile allows you to build an .IPA file and share that with beta testers (assuming of course you included their device id in the profile, or you have an Enterprise account/profile). They can install the .IPA file via iTunes (so they don't have to be a developer, or on Mac for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry!! you can't.

App Store > create a distribution provisioning profile to submit to the App Store
Ad Hoc > create a distribution provisioning profile to install a limited number of registered devices.

So you need to create a new `Ad Hoc` type distribution profile to install your device.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is 'NO'. You can not use 'store distribution provisioning profile' for testing your app on a device. It is intended to be used only for submitting your app to App Store.

To test your app before you submit it to App Store, you need to create separate 'ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile'. This will help you to beta test your app before submission as refered here..
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1